# Secure Wiping of files in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, filestream, security

Given the path of a string i want to wipe out the contents of a file. The natural way I thought (which maybe incorrect) was to open a FileStream to the file and write gibberish (random data perhaps taken from a RNGCryptoServiceProvider) to it. And then perhaps do this several times and then delete the file.

My problem is that while this may look logically correct, i read up on another blog that Windows might actually choose to write the file to a different place in the hard disk.

Is that the case in Windows Mobile? Will this actually be a problem? Does this writing to a different location in the hard disk apply to even flash based (SD etc) cards ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but the wear-levelling firmware for things like SD/SSD may make them *more* susceptible to this.

Comment: @Marc: yes, the wear levelling down in the card is certainly going to make them very susceptible.  Same for on-board flash.

Comment: So just over writing the file with 1's and 0's several times would not ensure that the file is securely over written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not personally done this, but you will probably need to use the low-level FLASH driver IOCTLs to do this correctly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa927166.aspx

I think [IOCTL_FMD_RAW_WRITE_BLOCKS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931977.aspx) looks particularly useful.

-PaulH

---

Another possibility that may work would be to erase the file normally, then use the defragment APIs to wipe ALL of the freespace on your flash. Since you're wiping everything, it won't be necessary to know exactly where on the disk your file was. But, this will wear out your flash drive more quickly. The C# method is detailed in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx

Comment: He'd need to find the block where the file is for that to be of any use, plus if it's on a mounted store like a CF/SD card, this is not going to work as the card is probably doing wear-leveling and you don't have raw write access to where the data resides.

Comment: @ctacke - What about the defrag API [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx]? SDelete [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443] uses to locate files on the disk.

Comment: This question is about Windows CE / Windows Mobile so there are no defrag APIs.

Comment: @ctacke - Nuts. @Ranhiru Cooray - sorry, bud. you may be SOL.